# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}\{X\}=\mathbb{E}\{Y\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{E}\{X|\mathcal{F}\}=\mathbb{E}\{Y|\mathcal{F}\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Given $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P})$ and two r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ defined on it, does it hold true that:
$$\mathbb{E}\{X\}=\mathbb{E}\{Y\}\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}\{X|\mathcal{F}\}=\mathbb{E}\{Y|\mathcal{F}\}$$
? If so, how can one show that is true?

Comment: $\mathbb E[X | \mathcal F] = X$ almost surely, the same goes with $Y$, since both $X,Y$ must be (by definition) $\mathcal F$ measurable. So no, it is not true that $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[Y]$ implies that $X=Y$ a.s

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that it is true.

Now let $A\in\mathcal F$ such that $0<P(A)<1$.

Then we can find a constant $c$ with $P(A)=c(1-P(A))$.

Let $X:=\mathsf{1}_A$ and $Y:=c\mathsf{1}_{A^\complement}$ so that $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY$.

However then: $$P(A)=\mathbb EX\mathsf1_A=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal F]\mathsf{1}_A]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathcal F]\mathsf{1}_A]=\mathbb EY\mathsf1_{A}=0$$

This contradicts $0<P(A)$ and we conclude that for every $A\in\mathcal F$ we must have $P(A)\in\{0,1\}$.

That means that every random variable defined on the probability space is *degenerated*.

In that (uninteresting) situation the statement indeed holds.